# How do I work around the "The process cannot access the file .ISPAC because it is being used by another process" error?

Tags: visual-studio, ssis, sql-server-data-tools

I executed an SSIS package using SSDT and Visual Studio. When I try to execute another package I get an error saying "The process cannot access the file XXXX.ispac because it is being used by another process". I have tried rebooting but that is a pain in the behind. How can I work around this error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might check your patch level. I saw this much more frequently with the 2015 release of SSDT but hasn't bit me too often since then.

### Finding and killing a process

Sysinternals has an excellent tool called [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer). It's free, doesn't require an install and helps you see what all is happening on your computer. In this case, you want to find the process that has its grubby finger on your file (MyProject.ispac) and then kill it.

https://helpcenter.gsx.com/hc/en-us/articles/115015880627-How-to-Identify-which-Windows-Process-is-Locking-a-File-or-Folder

A different approach that doesn't require getting Process Explorer running is to change your build from Development to Release (and back again).

Chicken Sandwich No Pickles asks via comments

> How can I convert from Development to Release?

In your tool bar, click where you see Development in the dropdown (or right click the solution in Solution Explorer)

[image]

In Configuration manager, you may/may not have a listing available under Configuration. Earlier versions of SSIS projects had dev/release configurations predefined but it looks like newer ones do not. If you do not have another option, make one via `<New...>`

[image]

Copy the values from the Development configuration et voilà!

[image]

Now when you debug, ProjectFolder/bin/Release will exist and the dtsdebughost.exe will latch onto that file and release the pointers to ProjectFolder/bin/Development/Project.ispac

Comment: How can I convert from Development to Release?

Comment: @ChickenSandwichNoPickles Added an explanation

Answer (score 46):

While developing an SSIS package I got the error *“The process cannot access the file ‘*.*ispac*’ because it is being used by another process”*.

Tried to close SSDT and run it again but, we still got the same error while compiling. Then, after searching over internet, we got the solution:

**Solution :**

1. Go to Task Manager–> Details Tab.
2. Locate the process “DtsDebugHost.exe“.
3. Kill this process.

There might be multiple instances of this process. Kill all of them.
After doing this, I tried to compile the package again and it was successful.

Comment: The process name for DtsDebugHost.exe in Task Manager might be seen  as SSIS Debug Host.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a simple script you can run in powershell to kill all ssis debug process "DtsDebugHost.exe" and unlock the ispac file.

unlock_ispac.ps1

```
# if ssis error with 'The process cannot access the file ‘.ispac'
# run this file in powershell
get-process | foreach {
    $pName = $_
    if($pName.Name -eq "DtsDebugHost") {
        $pName.Kill()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

if anyone's in a hurry just run this in cmd prompt:

```
taskkill /im DtsDebugHost.exe /f
```

all other answers explain this well. this is just if you're looking to copy/paste something to get it over with :)